# Azure Data Factory not visible in PowerShell environment

Tags: powershell, azure-data-factory

I have been created several Azure Data Factories on the Portal then I would like to monitor them from PowerShell. 
After login to my subscription via PS I have tried this command:

```
Get-AzureRmDataFactory -ResourceGroupName 'Myresource'
```

and get back only the PS prompt nothing else (neither Data Factory names nor an error message).

On the Portal still I see the Data Factories.
If I create a Data Factory via PS with 
`New-AzureRmDataFactory` command then I see that Data Factory on the Portal and on the PS, too.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you try selecting the subscription ? Incase if you have multiple ones

Comment: Fortunately, I have only one subscription.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using ADF v1 or v2?

If v2, you can try `Get-AzureRmDataFactoryV2 -ResourceGroupName "Myresource"`
.